# System get stuck when filtered by DateTime in .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a function which generates the list of workorders:

```
 public async Task<Object> GetAllWorkOrdersForUserAsync(string from,string to, int start, int length)
        {

                IQueryable<ReportWorkOrderViewModel> resp;
          
                resp = (from wo in _dbContext.WorkOrders
                        join woc in _dbContext.WorkOrderCategory on wo.WorkOrderCategoryId equals woc.Id
                        join sc in _dbContext.ServiceClients on wo.ServiceClientId equals sc.Id
                        join usr in _dbContext.Users on wo.UserId equals usr.Id into user
                        from uur in user.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join contractor in _dbContext.Users on wo.ContractorId equals contractor.Id into contr
                        from contor in contr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new ReportWorkOrderViewModel
                        {
                            Id = wo.Id,
                            WorkOrderType = woc.Name,
                            CustomerName = sc.FirstName + " " + sc.LastName,
                            CustomerAccount = wo.ServiceClientId,
                            AppointmentDate = wo.StartDateTime.ToString(),
                            IsHiring = (userId == wo.UserId),
                            CreatedAtDate = wo.CreatedAt.ToString(),
                            CreatedAtTime = wo.CreatedAt.ToString(),
                            CreatedBy = uur != null ? (uur.CompanyName != string.Empty ? uur.CompanyName : uur.ContactFirst + " " + uur.ContactLast) : string.Empty,
                            AssignedTechnician = contor != null ? (contor.ContactFirst + " " + contor.ContactLast) : string.Empty,
                            AppointmentTime = wo.StartDateTime.ToString(),
                            City = sc.City,
                            State = sc.State,
                            TicketStatus = wo.Status,
                            CompletionNote = wo.WorkPerformedDetail,
                            ClientsNote = wo.CustomerNotes,
                            TechStatus = wo.TechStatus == TechnicianStatus.Arrived ? "Arrivied" : wo.TechStatus == TechnicianStatus.OnTheWay ? "On The Way" : "Init",
                        });


            int totalRows = resp.Count();

            
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(from) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(to))
            {
                try
                {
                    DateTime fromDate = DateTime.Parse(from);
                    DateTime toDate = DateTime.Parse(to);

                   resp = resp.AsEnumerable().Where(d => Convert.ToDateTime(d.AppointmentDate) >= fromDate && Convert.ToDateTime(d.AppointmentDate) <= toDate).AsQueryable();
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }


            int totalRowsAfterFiltering = resp.Count();
            //<!--sorting-->
            resp = resp.OrderBy(searchColumnName + " " + sortDirection);
            
           
            //<!--paging-->
            if (paginate)
            {
                if (totalRowsAfterFiltering != totalRows)
                {
                    resp = resp.Skip(start).Take(length);
                }
                else
                {
                    resp = resp.Where(x => x.Id >= start).Take(length);
                }
            }
            var response = new
            {
                data = resp,
                recordsTotal = totalRows,
                recordsFiltered = totalRowsAfterFiltering
            };

            return response;
        }
```

My ViewModel is

```
 public class ReportWorkOrderViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string WorkOrderType { get; set; }
        public int CustomerAccount { get; set; }
        public string CustomerName { get; set; }

        private string appointmentDate;
        public string AppointmentDate { get => appointmentDate; set => appointmentDate = Convert.ToDateTime(value).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); }
        private string appointmentTime;
        public string AppointmentTime { get => appointmentTime; set => appointmentTime = Convert.ToDateTime(value).ToString("HH:mm tt"); }
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
}
```

The above function works fine and generates all the list when there no value for From and To. The total items in the list are 6-7000, but when i need the list  of data filtering through date and time. My System gets stuck in `int totalRowsAfterFiltering = resp.Count();` this part of code for 15-20second and finally populated 2/3 data only. But When I don't filter by date the list is executed in 2 second. What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you try without `AsEnumerable()` like: `resp = resp.Where(d => Convert.ToDateTime(d.AppointmentDate) >= fromDate && Convert.ToDateTime(d.AppointmentDate) <= toDate);`

Comment: @Jaggan_j I tried without AsEnumerable() but I am getting an error

``` LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression. ```

Comment: I think its good practice to define `AppointmentDate data type` as `DateTime` instead of `string`.